# how can i change frequency of recorded sound in android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am developing an android application that records through MIC and changes its frequency. Similar to Helium booth app for iphone. For the time being i have written code to record a file and save it in sdcard. Now my question is that can i change frequency of the sound while recording? or can i set frequency in which audio should be recorded.
Following is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaRecorder recorder;
  File audiofile = null;
  private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingActivity";
  private View startButton;
  private View stopButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startButton = findViewById(R.id.start);
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                startRecording(v);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopRecording(v);

        }
    });
}

 public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {

        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);

        File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
          audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
          return;
        }
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
      }

      public void stopRecording(View view) {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
      }

      protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: Don't record compressed audio (like AMR) if you intend to process the audio afterwards. Use the AudioRecord class to record uncompressed PCM instead. Also, I'm guessing that you want to change the _pitch_ of the audio (rather than doing something like a time stretch), but you might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: i tried working with AudioRecord too. But i got stuck in some errors that i was not able to solve. so i decided to go with Mediarecorder.
So are you telling me that i cannot do it with MediaRecorder? and yes i do want to change pitch of the audio too.

Comment: MediaRecorder only supports recording of compressed audio (some vendors add support for linear PCM, but that's not officially supported so trying to use it would make your app break on many devices). Compressed audio is not suitable for editing since it would require transcoding the audio, thereby degrading the quality even further.

Comment: @micheal. Please give a look at this post too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384221/getting-error-code-20-with-audiorecord-instance